# How can I go through a vector in R Dataframe

Tags: r, dataframe

I have a dataframe that looks like this

```
Name   Cricket   Football   Swimming 
A      Y         Y          N
B      N         Y          N
C      Y         N          Y
```

I want a code that goes through all the columns and flags each entry using the column name like this:

```
Name   Cricket   Football   Swimming   Sports
A      Y         Y          N          Cricket and Football
B      N         Y          N          Football Only
C      Y         N          Y          Cricket and Swimming
```

I have an idea of using ifelse() but it would be tedious if the dataframe increases in number of columns and i need something dynamic which i do not need to change everytime.

please help!!

Answer (score 4, accepted):

An option would be to `gather` the data into 'long' format, `filter` the rows with 'Y', grouped by 'Name', paste the elements in 'key' (`str_c`) and `left_join` with the original dataset

```
library(tidyverse)
df1 %>%
   gather(key, val, -Name) %>% 
   filter(val == 'Y') %>% 
   group_by(Name) %>% 
   summarise(Sports = str_c(key, collapse= ' and ')) %>%
   left_join(df1) %>%
   select(names(df1), "Sports")
# A tibble: 3 x 5
#  Name  Cricket Football Swimming Sports              
#  <chr> <chr>   <chr>    <chr>    <chr>               
#1 A     Y       Y        N        Cricket and Football
#2 B     N       Y        N        Football            
#3 C     Y       N        Y        Cricket and Swimming
```

#### data

```
df1 <- structure(list(Name = c("A", "B", "C"), Cricket = c("Y", "N", 
"Y"), Football = c("Y", "Y", "N"), Swimming = c("N", "N", "Y"
)), class = "data.frame", row.names = c(NA, -3L))
```

Comment: Thank you akrun this was really helpful

Answer (score 1):

Something like this (in base R) would do it too:

```
df$Sports <- apply(df[,-1]=="Y", 1, function(r) paste(names(df)[-1][r], collapse=" and "))

#  Name Cricket Football Swimming               Sports
#1    A       Y        Y        N Cricket and Football
#2    B       N        Y        N             Football
#3    C       Y        N        Y Cricket and Swimming
```